# SSL Client/Server error

Tags: java, ssl, server, client

I have a simple client/server program that authenticates using SSL. The program compiles and run free from error but when I send a message form the client side to the server the following error occurs in client side:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2011)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1113)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:735)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    at EchoClient.main(EchoClient.java:32)
```

And this error is shown in the server side:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1937)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:292)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:1014)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:731)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:213)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:969)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:904)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1050)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:916)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at EchoServer.main(EchoServer.java:26)
```

My server code is as follows:

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public
class EchoServer {

    public static void main(String[] arstring) {
        try {


            SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLServerSocket sslserversocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(9999);
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();

            sslsocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"SSLv3", "TLSv1"}); 

            InputStream inputstream = sslsocket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

            String string = null;
            while ((string = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(string);
                System.out.flush();
            }

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I run it with the following command: `java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=mySrvKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=raina141 EchoServer`

And my Client code is as follows:

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.*;

public
class EchoClient {

    public static void main(String[] arstring) {
          //  System.out.println("Type in a message to send to Server");

        try {
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("localhost", 9999);
            sslsocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"SSLv3", "TLSv1"}); 

            InputStream inputstream = System.in;
            InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

            OutputStream outputstream = sslsocket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream);
            BufferedWriter bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(outputstreamwriter);

            String string = null;
           // if ((string = bufferedreader.readLine()) == "end"){
             //   bufferedwriter.write("Communication closed by Client");
               // bufferedwriter.flush();
            //}

            while ((string = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                bufferedwriter.write(string + '\n');
                bufferedwriter.flush();

            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I run it with the following command:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mySrvKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=raina141 EchoClient
```

Comment: What is the version number of the java run time?

Comment: Java SE 8 1.8.0_40.jdk    @Gary